# ConnectionRequest response handling

Tags: java, json, codenameone

I am trying to write the response data getting from ConnectionRequest to local Json file in Codename one, but I don't have any idea of where to start... Anybody have any clue about this so please post your answer.

Comment: `In Codename one` - what do you mean?

Comment: Take a look at the PropertyCross demo

Comment: @Divers https://www.codenameone.com/

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using `ConnectionRequest.setDestinationFile()` to download content to a local file.

```
private static boolean downloadUrlTo(String url, String fileName, boolean showProgress, boolean background, boolean storage, ActionListener callback) {
        ConnectionRequest cr = new ConnectionRequest();
        cr.setPost(false);
        cr.setFailSilently(true);
        cr.setDuplicateSupported(true);
        cr.setUrl(url);
        if(callback != null) {
            cr.addResponseListener(callback);
        }
        if(storage) {
            cr.setDestinationStorage(fileName);
        } else {
            cr.setDestinationFile(fileName);
        }
        if(background) {
            NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(cr);
            return true;
        } 
        if(showProgress) {
            InfiniteProgress ip = new InfiniteProgress();
            Dialog d = ip.showInifiniteBlocking();
            NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(cr);
            d.dispose();
        } else {
            NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(cr);
        }
        return cr.getResponseCode() == 200;
    }
```

[See full source](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/Version-3.6/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/io/Util.java#L1316-L1343)

Answer (score 1):

The following code would get a JSON object from a server and save it to a local file.

```
String fspath = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath();
String url = "http://example.com/getSomeJSON.php";

ConnectionRequest cr = new ConnectionRequest(url, false);
cr.setDestinationFile(fspath + "mylocalfile.json");
NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(cr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you actually want to do, but for handling JSON objects, you might want to to try the Framework provided by json.org: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json
With this, you can convert a response into a JSON object and then extract data from this object.

This is an example for a HTTP-POST-request:

```
    public class PostTest {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

    try { 
        //This section is for creating and executing the POST-Request
        URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder("http://www.example.com/");
        URI uri = uriBuilder.build();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);

        //This section converts the response into a HttpEntity
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());

        //This converts the HttpEntity into a JSON Object
        if (entity != null) {
            String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            JSONObject responseObject = responseString.getJSONObject();
        }

    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

If the request was successfull, you could now extract data from the `responseObject` like this:

```
String fieldContent = responseObject.getString("fieldName");
System.out.println("Example field: " + fieldContent);
```

where `fieldName` represents the name of a variable used in `responseObject`

I realise that this will probably not be the exact scenario you are looking for, but I hope it might give you an idea.